# replace : with _ from Get-Date result

Tags: powershell

I get the date in powershell. The output has : and i want to replace it to _,

```
 Get-Date -format  u
 result
 2014-05-14 16:26:45Z
```

I want to replace the : with _

```
 Get-Date -format u | $_ -replace ":","_"
```

Not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of replacing after the fact, you can just use a format specifier that does what you want:

```
get-date -format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ssZ'
```

Answer (score 3):

The pipeline doesn't work quite like that.

Instead, treat the result of `get-date` as an object/variable, and use `-replace` on that.

```
(get-date -Format u) -replace ":","_";
```

Or, since it's just a string, use the `replace()` method

```
(get-date -Format u).Replace(":","_");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
PS H:\> get-date -format u | % {$_.Replace(":","_")}
2014-05-14 09_41_05Z
PS H:\>
```